# How to add SAML authentication to MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, saml

We need to add SAML support to our existing MVC application to support SSO for a client.

They have built a custom SAML authentication server using https://simplesamlphp.org/

I was hoping there would be an easy way (perhaps a nuget package) - we could use to achieve this.

However all plugins\code I find seem to be very specific for Sharepoint, Google, Okta etc.

What is the easiest way to achieve this for an existing MVC 4 application

Thanks

Comment: Number of options - both free and commercial - here: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43

Comment: Hi Always Learning :   Can you please help here. I need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Sustainsys](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/) or [ITFoxtec](https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2) are good options for implementing a SAML service provider in .NET

Answer (score 0):

The below url of Sustainsys does not see

Following is the working url

[Sustainsys](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/v2/getting-started.html)