# SAML 2 implementation in exiting .Net Core API login service

Tags: .net, .net-core, saml-2.0

I need to implement SAML 2.0 to an already existing login service, but are new to SAML and having a hard time finding libraries or any more technical information of how this should be implemented.

We currently have a .Net Core API that works as an authentication service handling users trying to login to some servers we provide, and this is working without any problem. A global front web site retrieves the users login information, which is sent to this API, which returns a token and a list of available servers to connect to. The user chooses one or several of these servers, and each server can verify the token with the login service to accept the user as authenticated.

Now I've got a request to try to make it possible to also sign in via SAML, and technically this shouldn't be a big problem, but I can't find much information of how to implement this from the Core API perspective. My hope is to make it possible for the web site to not act as the service provider, but let the API do this instead.

Is there anyone who can point me into any good direction, have any experience with this or know any good libraries that can help?

Comment: Duplicate of [57318579](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318579/how-to-add-saml-authentication-to-mvc-application/57329899) . The libs mentioned in the answer do work with .NET Core as well as plain ASP.NET et al.