# SAML implementation using ping federate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I'm completely new to SAML. I'm implementing it using ping authority. I don't found a proper guide for implementing it in c# mvc application. Any sample code or complete guide provided would be very helpful. Thank's

I have tried using sustainsys saml .net plugin. it works fine, but I can't implement it using ping federate.

Comment: You have to be more specific on why Sustainsys.Saml2 doesn't work with Ping. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Recommended way of Getting Started: read the [SAML Technical Overview](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf), then have a look at [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318579/how-to-add-saml-authentication-to-mvc-application/57329899) of the previous questions on SO that address this.

Comment: What the scenario is, I was able to get the Idp login page. After entering credentials it navigates to IdP and from then I was unable to get the authenticated request. I would like to how to configure my SP and use the metadata file which has been sent by the IdP.

Answer (score 0):

SAML IMPLEMENTATION WITH PINGFEDERATE :

1. Install pingfederate on your server
2. Connect Your active directory with pingfederate account so users are authenticated 
   on pingfederate login window.
3. Create Service Provider Connection in pingfederate.
4. you can use pingfederate X.509 Certificate or use your certificate with service 
   provider connection.
5. Add attributes that you want to share with you service provider like username and email 
   address.
6. After creating SP connection you get "SSO Application Endpoint"
   Ex: https://your.domain.server:port/idp/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=Service provider
7. Using "SSO Application Endpoint URL" you can navigate your SP to move on pingfederate 
   account login.
8. After that in service provider section implement saml section by validating ping 
   federate x:509 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Nandam, you need to implement the step for metadata exchange between your Identity Provider (IDP) and Service Provider (SP). [Here is the Pingfederate document which defines the exchange of xml metadata](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-93/page/bdx1564002975039.html) between the two entities. Bear in mind this exchange of xml data includes endpoint URLs, binding types, attributes. [Read how to export/import](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-93/page/wxr1564002975101.html) the xml metadata. This is basic step that has to be completed.