# Get UserID from SAML within web application

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, onelogin

I am a new developer and I am unfamiliar with SAML, however, I am needing to add some functionality to a dotnetcore framework web app that uses SAML to log in. I need to be able to Get the SAML UserID of the current user in order to update the UserID database field when the user makes changes to the database. I will appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have not tried anything.  I am also new to Stack Overflow and I didn't read that I shouldn't post about anything I haven't tried. I am sorry that I prematurely posted the question.  I have been researching, but I haven't found anything that would appear to work for me yet.

Comment: Dont worry about it. Welcome to stackoverflow. Usually you will have more audience to the post when you nail it down to the specifics. Currently the possibilies on how to achieve this varies a lot on how your   Saml is configured and also how your web app does it. Is it possible to include som2 code for us to look at ?

Comment: Thank you for the greeting.  I will post some code as soon as I can get my head wrapped around this problem a bit more.  I still have a lot to understand about how SAML works.

Comment: Recommended way of Getting Started: read the [SAML Technical Overview](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf), then have a look at [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318579/how-to-add-saml-authentication-to-mvc-application/57329899) of the previous questions on SO that address this.